# Diagram for data and processes

Tags: architecture, uml, modeling, diagram, dataflow

Which diagram should I use to describe such chain:

```
Input data->preprocessing->preprocessed data->
algorithm 1->if a good result, next step, if not - do algorithm 1 again...
```

Comment: Did you try doing some basic research? Show what effort did you put in solving your problem.

Comment: @Ister UML sequence diagram seems working but it is highly relies on time. I am looking for the very simplified version to show the data flow and sequence in the program

Comment: What other diagrams have you considered?

Comment: @Ister lots of wrong diagrams such as IDEFx and others.

Comment: When you write `do algorithm 1 again`, on which data do you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UML typically provides several types of diagrams that can serve this purpose, depending on your specific goal.

From comments it seems that the most suitable one is Activity Diagram. It allows to show the flow of activity together with the data used during the flow.

Second option would be a Sequence Diagram that you have already mentioned, however as you suggest in your question it is more focused on timing of events than on the actions itself. That's why Activity Diagram seems more suitable for your particular purpose.

If you don't want to limit yourself to UML only, especially if it is either a high-level approach or close to the business rather than strict development you may also consider BPMN as a good alternative.